# SOAP complex type in header

Tags: soap, blackberry, service

I am learning how to consume .net web services. I am using 4.7 JDE in Eclipse, testing in the Curve (8520) simulator 4.6.1.272. I generated the stubs using Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.

One of the services requires a complex type in the SOAP header (not in the SOAP body).

Is it possible to do that using the stubs created by the toolkit?

Comment: Try it, and if it fails, ask ;)

Comment: Why would you need complex class in header? Can you post your soap xml?

Answer (score 0):

depends what you mean by complex class
[Introduction to J2ME Web Services](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/wsa/):

> Let's briefly examine WSDL-to-Java data type mapping in JSR 172's JAX-RPC subset API:
>   ...
>   xsd:complexType - Sequence of primitive and class types

also see  [Types Supported by JAX-RPC](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC4.html)